# How to get Python 2.6 documentation of the future-imported print() function?

Tags: python, printing, pydoc

I use Python 2.6 with the new `print()` function:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Now, how can I get `pydoc` to print a documentation of that function? A simple

```
$ pydoc print
```

will print documentation about the 2.6 version of the print function.

(Needless to say, I can find the documentation online but I'd like to be able to access it using pydoc on the command line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no shortcut:

```
$ python -c 'from __future__ import print_function; help(print)'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what you want, but on my system, I can do `pydoc3.2 print` as I have both python 2.6 and python 3.2 installed...